# I deployed a contract USING Remix IDE and Metamask and i cant ADD liquidity

Tags: liquidity

i deployed a contract on BSCHAIN (its EVM machine i hope you dont mind)and i cant ADD LP practically does nothing,verification passed compilation as well i think might be an error in the code i wrote that doesnt allow to send to dex,in between wallets i could send both in testnet and on mainet here is the contract:

```
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);

constructor() {
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
}

function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns(uint) {
    return balances[owner];
}
function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
    require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >=value, "balance too low");
    balances[to] += value;
    balances[msg.sender] -= value;
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
    return true;
}

function trasferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
    require(balanceOf(from) >= 0, "balance too low");
    require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= 0, "allowance too low");
    balances[to] += value;
    balances[from] -= value;
    emit Transfer(from, to, value);
    return true;
}
function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns(bool) {
    allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
    return true;
}
```

}

Later Edit ;i receive in fact this error! Add liquidity failed: Unknown error: "The contract function "addLiquidityETH" reverted with the following reason: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED". Try increasing your slippage tolerance.
Dismiss
i cant see the error in the code may i ask for a little help please?

tnkx

Comment: there is no router in the contract

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue for last couple of days.

```
Add liquidity failed: Unknown error: "The contract function "addLiquidityETH" reverted with the following reason: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED".
```

Try increasing your slippage tolerance
I increased the slippage tolerance to 22% but nothing working.

My Contract Address : https://bscscan.com/address/0x478e63a7c15bbc5686f3fd1024550b5072d7c4f6
Source code is verified and available

Comment: Just a reminder that high slippage can make you vulnerable to sandwiching attacks, if you are on a chain that has infra for private txs (such as Flashbots Protect on Ethereum), try to use that